# Does the server execution plan use the index

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have added an index on the column “LastChangeDate” in table dbo.Employee. Will the SQL Server execution plan use this index in both the cases below? Can somebody explain why or why not.

```
SELECT EmployeeName  
FROM dbo.Employee  
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -2, LastChangeDate) >= ‘2016-01-01’ 

SELECT EmployeeName  
FROM dbo.Employee  
WHERE LastChangeDate >= ‘2016-01-01’
```

Comment: what kind of index is?

Comment: SQL column indexing

Comment: Have you seemed your execute plan?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first cannot use an index, because `LastChangeDate` is the argument to a function.  The only function (as far as I know) in SQL Server that does not disallow an index is conversion to a date.

The second might or might not use an index.  If you have a clustered index on `LastChangeDate`, then it should.  However, the query is presumably not very selective -- meaning that it selects a significant portion of all rows.  In such circumstances, the database optimizer may decide to forego the index and do a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

when you utilize it as function like you first select , you can't,
but for 2nd select if you used clustered index then you can(this is why I asking the type of index you used...)